# Is there a difference between array.size(); and size(array); in C++?

Tags: c++

Is there a difference between
`array.size();`
and
`size(array);` 
? How to tackle checking it? Or maybe it's the exact same function?

```
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::array<std::string, 3> arr {"John, Amber"};

    std::cout << "arr.size(); method: " << arr.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "size(arr); method: " << size(arr) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See Possible implementation
 in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size

Comment: `std::size` is a one-fits-all solution. It works with C-style array, all STL containers or any class that has `size() const` method.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Surely you meant to say that `std::size` is a one-`size`-fits-all solution?

Comment: Are there performance differences or if not then why are there 2 options of size usage?

Comment: Likely no performance difference, compiler should be able to inline that call. `std::size` was introduced in C++17 (19 years after fisrt C++ standard and many more after first C++ implementations) to allow for more generic handling of containers. With `std::size` (and `std::begin` and `std::end`) you don't need extra code to handle C-style arrays specifically, you can accept a (template) "container" by reference and it will work with both arrays and classes that have `size()` method. Before C++17, you needed extra function(s) to handle arrays.

Comment: are you refereing to `std::array` when you say "array" ? With a c-array `array.size()` wont work.

Comment: On a related note, there has been an effort to standardize [*uniform calling syntax*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Function_Call_Syntax#C++_proposal) in C++, but the effort has so far not met with success.

Comment: If you added a really small (like 3 lines of actual code, and like 3 `#include` lines, probably) [mcve] showing what exactly you mean by `array` and `size`, that'd be great.

Comment: Added a sample code, @hyde !

Comment: Thanks everyone, I think I get a gist of what might be the difference, with c-arrays and generic handling containers. Btw is the question downvoted due to lack of sample code or there was more to it? I want to learn to ask the questions properly!

Comment: @VeritAeternae [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @VeritAeternae Reasons for down-votes are sometimes difficult to know, but in this case, I'd guess the initial version of the question was indeed a bit vague, and then this is kind of asking a very basic question. But with the sample code showing exactly what you mean, I think it's a valuable question, and hope it'll gets re-opened.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? Obviously there's a syntactic difference, which you know because you wrote different syntax. And it's not the same function, because that isn't how function call syntax works. So are you _only_ concerned about performance, and if what happened when you measured and/or disassembled them both?

Comment: @Useless Since there are 2 functions that do the same thing, then it raises a question why are there 2, and it's either because the object on which the syntax is used differs or there is an implementation (performance) difference. I suppose this is what I want to know - any difference there is. I'm being extra paranoid. 
From what I understood and from the duplicate question someone linked with empty(), size(arr) would use an overload and return arr.size() so it's the same function; however c-arrays don't have member function .size() so they use a free function size(arr).