# Difference between std::vector::empty and std::empty

Tags: c++, std

To check if a vector `v` is empty, I can use [`std::empty(v)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/empty) or [`v.empty()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/empty). I looked at the signatures on cppreference, but am lacking the knowledge to make sense of them. How do they relate to each other? Does one implementation call the other?

I know that one comes from the containers library and the other from the iterators library, but that is about it.

Comment: They do the same thing but `std::empty` didn't exist until C++17.

Comment: This is eerily similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/71998235/817643 - asked earlier today

Comment: `std::empty(v)` uses the first overload, whose behavior is described as "1) returns `c.empty()`". They're the same.

Comment: @NathanPierson that should be posted as an answer

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Whoops. I tried searching, I promise! So I guess mine could be a duplicate...

Comment: The other one doesn't have an answer posted, so it's not a proper dupe target. I was just taken aback by the similarity.

Comment: Side note for later: Take a look at the possible implementations given at the cppreference links you used. The stuff may look like Martian now, but before long you'll be able to understand them and get all sorts of useful information out of them.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I wrote an answer that covers both questions. That question could now technically be a dupe of this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Difference between std::vector::empty and std::empty

The difference between `Container::empty` member function and `std::empty` free function (template) is the same as difference between `Container::size`,`std::size`, `Container::data`,`std::data`, `Container::begin`,`std::begin` and `Container::end`,`std::end`.

In all of these cases for any standard container, the free function (such as `std::empty`) simply calls the corresponding member function. The purpose for the existence of the free function is to provide a uniform interface between containers (and also `std::initializer_list`) and arrays. Arrays cannot have member functions like the class templates can have, so they have specialised overload for these free functions.

If you are writing code with a templated container type, then you should be using the free function in order to be able to support array as the templated type. If the type isn't templated, then there is no difference between the choice of using member function or the free function other than the convenience of potential refactoring into a template (or just plain array).

Comment: "If you are writing code with a templated container type, then you should be using the free function in order to be able to support array as the templated type" -- while this is true, you may occasionally feel strong or even overwhelming urges to yell at your caller that if they insist on having an array they can jolly well wrap it in `boost::iterator_range` (or whatever it is) and leave you out of it. Try to remain calm, this will pass.

Comment: The motivation of C-style array makes sense. Just out of curiosity: do you happen to have a source handy (like some specification) where this argument is made?

Comment: @lursyy Most changes to C++ standard are made through proposal documents where you can typically find a rationale. Especially for later standards, those documents are freely available through the standard organisation's website. The proposal that suggested these (aside from `begin` and `end` which were already introduced in C++11) is N4017. Technically, I hadn't read the proposal that suggested adding these to the standard, so I explained the only use case I could come up with. I've looked it up, and array support exactly the rationale.

Answer (score 11):

There are three overloads of `std::empty`, but the one used by `std::empty(v)` for a vector `v` is the first:

```cpp
template <class C>
constexpr auto empty(const C& c) -> decltype(c.empty()); // (since c++17, until c++20)

template <class C>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto empty(const C& c) -> decltype(c.empty());
(since C++20) // (since c++20)
```

This overload has the following effect:

> 1. returns `c.empty()`

So, `std::empty(v)` and `v.empty()` have the same effect in this case.

Answer (score 6):

`std::empty` returns the result of calling `std::vector::empty`.

`std::empty` is useful for scenarios where a container may or may not provide a member function `empty()` for types providing a member function `empty`, `std::empty` provides a default implementation, but for a custom type not providing this function you can provide a function `empty` at namespace scope for use in templates; thanks to argument dependent lookup the function in the same namespace as the parameter will be used as fallback:

```
namespace Custom
{
    struct Container
    {
        bool m_empty;
    };

    constexpr bool empty(Container const& c) // custom implementation for our own type
    {
         return c.m_empty;
    }
}

template<class T>
void PrintEmpty(char const* containerName, T&& container)
{
    using namespace std;
    std::cout << containerName << " is " << (empty(container) ? "empty" : "not empty") << '\n';
}

int main()
{
    PrintEmpty("std::vector<int>()", std::vector<int>());
    PrintEmpty("Container{}", Custom::Container{});
    PrintEmpty("Container{ true }", Custom::Container{ true });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

To language-lawyer a bit, the C++20 standard says that a container `a` has its  `a.empty()` member function return `true` if and only if `a.begin() == a.end()` ([container.requirements.general]).

The `std::empty()` non-member function is specified in [iterator.range].  The overload `constexpr auto empty(const C& c)` “*Returns:* `c.empty()`.”

So, in the Standard, the non-member function is specified in terms of the member functions, not vice versa.  In general, that doesn’t mean that the implementation needs to have the non-member function actually call the member function, so long as it “behaves as if.”  In this case, the relationship must hold for any allowed specialization of the STL container classes, or for custom container classes, so that constrains what the writers of the library are allowed to do.

Comment: "nothing prevents" isn't correct -- the Standard algorithms including `std::empty()` have to work with custom container types as well as allowed specializations of Standard classes.

Comment: @BenVoigt As I understand it, the non-member function `constexpr bool std::empty(const std::vector<T>& c)` could be an overload, and the member function could be implemented as a wrapper to `return std::empty(*this);` Which might be implemented as `return c.begin() == c.end();`, or `return c.size() == 0;` Perhaps unlikely, but allowed.

Comment: Not allowed, that signature potentially matches a custom specialization of `std::vector`, see https://eel.is/c++draft/constraints#namespace.std-2

Comment: @BenVoigt Okay, but `std::vector<bool>` would be allowed to do it, since an overload for that doesn’t interfere with any other specialization?

Comment: @BenVoigt I’ll correct my last sentence. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Any instantiation of `std::vector<T>` where `T` is not a user-defined type is guaranteed to use the library-provided `std::vector` class.  That includes when `T` is `bool`.

Comment: @BenVoigt But if `std::vector<bool>::empty` needs to be an overload—for instance, because it needs to have an unusual iterator type and wants to compare `c.size()` rather than `c.begin()` and `c.end()`—there’s nothing stopping it from implementing the specialized `std::vector<bool>::empty` function as a wrapper for `std::empty(const std::vector<bool>&)` instead of vice versa, right? That wouldn’t break any other custom class or specialization, would it?

Comment: @BenVoigt Anyway, I’ve edited in your correction. Thank you again for pointing it out!

Comment: I believe that you're correct that the "as-if" rule could be met by having `std::vector<bool, std::allocator<bool>>` have the member function `empty` call the non-member function.  But that's a lot of gymnastics to avoid what is a very simple and always correct implementation stated in the Standard.... after all if there's an alternative implementation of `empty` needed for `vector<bool>`, it can be done in the member `empty()`